# Google Maps API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError on play store

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

It has many answers online but still I am dumb enough to crack it myself :(.

I have an Ionic hybrid app (Ionic, angular and Visual Studio). Development is almost done and working fine. I have signed my app using .keystore certificate. I have also generated an API key in Google Console and gave it restriction on `HTTP Referrers (Web Site)`.

On my local (dev environment), it stopped working. So I added `http://localhost:4000/index.html#find` (or even `localhost`) as referrer to API key. This fixed the problem and now it is working fine.

However my app is not working in android device. I am not sure what should be the referrer URL there. As a trial, I debugged my device using visual studio. Following is the error that I tracked.

```
Google Maps API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-not-allowed-map-error
Your site URL to be authorized: file:///android_asset/www/index.html#find
```

However adding `file:///android_asset/www/index.html#find` as referrer is not solving the problem. To me it looks expected as they are pointing to raw file to my system (as I am debugging). So, what should be the value of this to make all devices work after I add my app to play store?

Do it has to come from `manifest.xml` or my app project? Or do I need to mention this somewhere in `Google Play Console`? Could anyone please guide me?

Answer (score 5):

The file:/ referrers are not supported in Cloud developer console at the moment.

You can consider two options:

1. Use a different API key without HTTP referrer restrictions
2. Purchase Premium plan where file:/ referrers are supported with client IDs.

There is an [issue 9996](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9996) in the public issue tracker regarding referrers with file:/// protocol. I would suggest starring the issue to express your interest and receive further updates.

**UPDATE**

Good news, Google has added support for file:/ referrers. You can see the following text in the documentation

`file:// referers need a special representation to be added to the Key restriction. The "file:/" part should be replaced with "__file_url__" before being added to the Key restriction. For example, "file://path/to/" should be formatted as "__file_url__/path/to/*". After enabling file:// referers, it is recommended you regularly check your usage, to make sure it matches your expectations`

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#key-restrictions

Comment: My app is free without ads, so I would prefer not to go for Premium.
Regarding `Use a different API key without HTTP referrer restrictions`, you mean I should use `None` restriction.

1. Is it possible to use `None` when I sign my app with keystore?
2. Is it safe? Can I use android as restriction (or android is only for native apps)?
3. Earlier with `None`, I wasn't able to load my markers on map due to signing my app but not attaching `Sha1` key to the API key.

Comment: You authorize Maps Javascript API, so Android app restriction shouldn't work. The None should work with Maps JavaScript API, but it is not safe because your API key is exposed in the code. So the 9996 is the issue that should solve this security flaw.

Comment: For ios the _file_ didn't work for me. I needed to add * as a referrer (basically allow any url).

Comment: @xomena - you referenced my other issue to here as a possible dup.   Reading this and rereading the google docs, for my ionic/cordova app - to lock my api keys down to only be able to be used by my app, does this mean I need to add some file to my app with the matching sha-1 fingerprint or something?   If so, what is the format of the file and where does the file go in the app project?  Or am I still not understanding this...

Comment: @xomena - according to this, Maps Javascript API can only be locked down via HTTP referer.  Or am I missing something?  https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#keysystem

Comment: @rolinger your understanding is correct. Maps JavaScript API may be protected only by referrer.