# How to restrict Google Map API key in mobile app?

Tags: android, iphone, cordova, google-maps-api-3, http-referer

I have a cordova/ionic mobile app that loads google maps (in the index.html main file) into the app (both android and ios) using: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AndroidKey` and `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=iOSKey`.  Each key is locked down with "app" restrictions and its not working.  I discovered that web service api's can only be locked down by HTTP referrer OR Server IP.

But since the maps are loaded directly via the client, there is no HTTP referrer by domain or a server IP...is there any other way I can lock down the API keys?

Can I use something like `https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP` to create an HTTP referer?  And if I can, what kind of legit domain referrer can I create that would work with google maps api HTTP referer restrictions?

update:
someone marked this as a dup, but that post is about Android SDK API, whereas mine is about Javascript Map API.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError on play store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41087892/google-maps-api-error-referernotallowedmaperror-on-play-store)

Comment: @xomena - you dup reference appears to be for the Android SDK API.  My post is asking about ways to lock down the Javascript Map API key.

Comment: I believe both questions refer to the hybrid apps. In case of hybrid app your referrer starts with file:// protocol.

Comment: @xomena - can you explain this further please?  Are you implying I can restrict Javascript Map API using a domain referrer with `file://` ?  But what file?  Whats in the file...where does it go..?  Is there specific documentation about this?  The `Note` in the Google Console API restrictions page refers to `file://` too but gives no specifics that I can find.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/51209730/5140781

Comment: @xomena - I looked at that thread and tried 10 different combinations of `http://localhost/index.html` (and various paths) as well as various combinations of `file:///android_assets/www/index.html` - but nothing is working.  The RefererNotAllowedMapError in console is showing me: Your site URL to be authorized: __file_url__//android_asset/www/index.html#/tab/map////` - but this and variations don't work either.

Comment: If the way described in documentation doesn't work, your only option is file a support case with Google Maps API team: https://console.developers.google.com/google/maps-apis/support

Answer (score 3):

in ionic 3/4/5 when using [`cordova-plugin-ionic-webview` (docs)](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/blob/master/README.md) the referrer is `ionic://localhost` for iOS and `http://localhost` for Android.

- first solution is to customize the scheme and/or hostname - this sounds like a reasonable option as this way the referrer can be set to sth like `https://mobileapp.author.domain.com/` which cannot be easily stolen by a website (well another app could possible set the same).
- similarly for capacitor `"server": {"hostname": "mobileapp.author.domain.com"}` can be used (as per this SO answer: [How to protect Google Maps API key on Ionic app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58826884/how-to-protect-google-maps-api-key-on-ionic-app) )
- quick'n'dirty option is to add a `*://localhost/*` as a website restriction - this is the only way I found to whitelist the `ionic://localhost/` referrer. This should also work for capacitor which uses `capacitor://localhost/`

Comment: I use Ionic to create app and test a lot of http restriction values and find pattern *://whatever-string/* can always pass google auth. Ex: I test  *://void/* and google auth still get passed but it's obvious void doesn't used in app as hostname.

Comment: I guess it probably because I test them on iOS simulator.