# How to protect Google Maps API key on Ionic app?

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, google-api, ionic4

I have Ionic PWA app published for Android and iOS (I used Capacitor to generate the native build). In the frontend code, it has my Google Maps API key, however, I can't restrict it to any of the options google offers because...

1. **HTTP referrers** - It's not on a public domain name, it's on a local host within the webview of the native app. `http://localhost/` for Android and `capacitor://localhost/` for iOS. It does not seem very secure to use these as restrictions as they are very generic, and all other apps will have the same ones.
2. **IP addresses** - For obvious reasons.
3. **Android Apps** - It's not within the native code, it's within a webview.
4. **iOS Apps** - It's not within the native code, it's within a webview.

   [image]

None of these options can work for my situation. So how can I protect my API key from abuse?

Any ideas? I can't be the only the one using Google Maps API within an Ionic app.

Comment: use native GoogleMap and follow this link it will help you https://baadiersydow.com/ionic-google-maps-geolocation-native-javascript-ios-android/

Comment: That's the whole point of using Capacitor. You don't have to use anything native.

Comment: @nachshonf I have the same issue, setting the hostname configuration causing other problems such as connection errors, did you managed to find a solution?

Comment: The whole point of Capacitor is *not* that you don’t have to use anything native. Being able to easily access native functionality when needed but abstract it away to make it cross platform is a key benefit

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can configure the hostname of capacitor apps

```
"server": {
    // You can configure the local hostname, but it's recommended to keep localhost
    // as it allows to run web APIs that require a secure context such as
    // navigator.geolocation and MediaDevices.getUserMedia.
    "hostname": "unique-app",
  }
```

and then restrict the the API keys to `capacitor://unique-app`

https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/basics/configuring-your-app

Comment: I'm having an issue... After building for prod, on iOS, the app opens with a blank white screen. This only happens if I set a custom hostname.

Comment: To get this to work on android, I also had to add a restriction for `https://unique-app/*`

Comment: Can't "hackers" just create their own Capacitor app where they set the hostname parameter to the same value as you? Then they could access the API and send unwanted requests. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In order to protect your API key you have to check the value of the `window.location.href` within a webview. I guess you will see something like `file://some/path`.

So you will need apply HTTP referrer restriction for this path. Note that URLs with a file:// protocol require special representation as explained in

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#restrict_key

> **Note:** file:// referers need a special representation to be added to the key restriction. The "file://" part should be replaced with "__file_url__" before being added to the key restriction. For example, "file:///path/to/" should be formatted as "__file_url__//path/to/*". After enabling file:// referers, it is recommended you regularly check your usage, to make sure it matches your expectations.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using Capacitor, and it pulls up the webview using localhost/ (android) and capacitor://localhost/ (iOS). It does not seem very secure to use these as restrictions as they are very generic, and all other apps will have the same ones. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Old question but still...

If you do not want to store the `api_key` in your app, request it at run time from your own server over a POST `https` request before running any Google Maps requests.

Comment: Not a good idea. You would be removing the key from the app but send it all around. Anyone could sniff your app, replicate the post calls and get your key. A solution would be to send lat/lng values to your backend and the backend call the Maps api and return you the address in the format your app needs. And also restrict the api key to your server's IP.