# How to secure Google Maps JS api key in Cordova app?

Tags: google-maps, cordova

The map is functioned in the client side and its key is in the cdn placed in the index.html file. How can I secure the api key so bandits wont steal it? Note: I am asking about a **Cordova app served from the user's localhost** - not a public domain under the web.

Comment: Not v familiar with Cordova, but looks like you can restrict this to an  Android app package and SHA1 certificate fingerprint / IOS bundle identifier

Comment: Figure out what is URL of your page in Web view. If it includes file:// protocol follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58828747/5140781.

Comment: I have restricted the key to the app bundle hash in android and app bundle id in ios and hope it works. not yet tested.